# Axis2 not working within JIRA plugin/Maven

Tags: maven, apache-axis, jira-plugin

I am writing a JIRA plugin to export fields from issues and send them to a web service.

This has me using Maven and I have decided to use axis2 to perform the communication with the web service. After spending much time setting up the right dependencies for Axis2 to work, I have it compiling and running without error.

The trouble is that the plugin I have created appears unable to connect to the service client. I added debug code through the web service stub and it appears to fail when calling:

```
_serviceClient = new org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient(configurationContext,_service);
```

The interesting point is that no error is thrown and so I am unable to determine what is actually happening.

Another interesting point is that when I run a unit test, it completes successfully and communicates with the web service as I would like.

The primary differences between the unit test and the plugin is that the plugin is running in a JIRA instance on tomcat and the unit test is just using junit.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be going wrong or what things I can check to get further details. Happy to provide further information if required.